# Darius as jungle

Tags: league-of-legends

So last game i joined a random match of league (unranked). Me being in a totally random mood i decided to go jungle Darius. The enemy turned out to have no jungler so that meant double top and bot and 1 mid. Right off the bat they stole my blue and seeing as Darius is extremely (and i mean EXTREMELY) mana hungry, this devastated my jungling even more. Is there any way to get back from this setback? Im not asking how to get back if the enemy steals blue, im asking more specifically how to get back to jungling after the enemy steals blue with a poor jungling champ.

Comment: Your last two sentences make your question someone confusing and unclear. Just so you know, you essentially ARE asking how to get back if the enemy steals blue, as the stradegies are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it Darius jungles just fine, so you may want to look up some guides on [Mobafire](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mobafire.com%2Fleague-of-legends%2Fdarius-guide&ei=dDCvUfibL4f00gGKwYDQDg&usg=AFQjCNFZ9WRhufgN7O8imXt_fnwMNA7mrw&sig2=nKhmFtGY1v9qsG1lk0459A&bvm=bv.47380653,d.dmQ) or your site of preference as your probably doing it wrong if your having that much difficulty.

In addition, the easiest way to counter a blue steal (aside from counter stealing), is to spam [Mana Potions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fleagueoflegends.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FMana_Potion&ei=tzCvUc7GEe220QHOxoDICA&usg=AFQjCNGymeE_3u2cKNG_O6xivVG1RFTpgQ&sig2=hba2p43ducp5aHlOXKpUng&bvm=bv.47380653,d.dmQ). You'd be amazed how much 5 mana pots and a [Faerie Charm](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fleagueoflegends.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FFaerie_Charm&ei=lDCvUZjQJcb10gHg0ICABA&usg=AFQjCNHKVHeWeIKNdY8NX-97X3dlXL6R8Q&sig2=wV3_TkJmDsODsT_ou6v4lQ&bvm=bv.47380653,d.dmQ) helps your mana.

Your gold is going to suffer a little bit from the Potions at 35 gold each, and the Charm which is another 180, however the Charm can be sold back for almost its full price, 126 gold, which isnt too bad.  With these you should have no problem continuing your clear.

This is not the only option one has, as I've already mentioned, the best thing to do is get your team to react fast and counter-steal the enemy team's blue. Another tactic is to simply duo top for a short while until your strong enough to jungle without needing blue so badly.

Comment: I didn't say build mana items. I said get a Faerie Charm and some Mana Potions.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Ok so one final question, do you buy these items pre-game or after your blue gets stolen. Personally for a tanky melee champ i start with 5 health pots, 1 mana pot and a rejuvenation bead. What should i change in that setup, if anything?

Comment: Why would you buy them pregame? Are you planning on your blue being stolen? This is a recovery strategy, not a preventive one.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I'd buy something else than a rejuvenation bead as well, to be honest.

Comment: @Ender no that was my question but ok so i can still start with my own opening-build (whatever that may be) and if i lose blue i buy faerie charm and mana pots. Thanks its clear now. Is this the only option if you lose your blue?

Comment: @Marco your really making me work for this check.

Comment: @Ender but ofcourse what would be the fun in just `checking` ;)

Comment: i just want to point out one thing about this answer that the majority of the time is a bad idea. if you lane with your teammate in top lane, and do not gain a significant advantage(i.e.- a kill or two on the enemy) when you leave lane to go jungle, the player staying top will be at a serious disadvantage as they will be the same level as the enemy, it will then be a 1v2, and not many champs are good at fighting against two in lane, even with a level advantage.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend taking this item if you're having mana problems with darius as a jungler:
[Spirit of the Elder Lizard](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_of_the_Elder_Lizard)

The way I see it this item could benefit Darius quite a bit. 
The unique passive that does true damage over time fits perfectly with his passive,
A bit of CDR since he is a skillbased bruiser, AD (duh), Health Regen - Mana Regen - Extra Damage to Minions = Perfect for mana hungry junglers.

Comment: Not sure how this specifically addresses recovering from a blue buff steal.

Comment: @Ender A blue buff steal cannot be planned correct? Then we agree that you will start by getting the machete. That you will not change. If your blue gets stolen though, you can kill a camp or two and return to base to get a quick Faerie Charm which is put to good use if you get an Elder later. I was giving a possible solution to both a blue buff steal and darius' mana problems in general.